# sendgrid mail sending error upon placing multiple receiver

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

I'm using `const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');` and utilizing sendgrid version 7.6.2.

When I'm adding two email addresses in array and passing that into `send()` or `sendMultiple()` it's throwing me error like this.

```
status: 'failed',
>    Error: Error: String expected for `email`
```

here's the section where I'm putting the multiple emails,

```
mailsTo = {
    email: ["demo@email.com", "demo1@email.com"],
    name: "demo",
    type: 'to'
}
```

here if I pass one email as in form of string the mail is getting triggered. Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/single-email-multiple-recipients.md) the addresses are to be passed as an array of [`EmailData`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/packages/helpers/classes/email-address.d.ts) (string or object with `email` and `name`).

Please try the following:

```
mailsTo = [
    {
        email: "demo@email.com",
        name: "demo"
    },
    {
        email: "demo1@email.com",
        name: "demo"
    }
]
```

Assuming `mailsTo` is being pass as the `to` parameter for

Comment: Now I'm getting ```{"message":"The to array is required for all personalization objects, and must have at least one email object with a valid email address.","field":"personalizations.0.to","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.personalizations.to"}
``` this error

Comment: Sorted. I had to use to as I was setting a template